# gunicorn randomly getting term and not restarting in systemd

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn in production with systemd. I periodically get `[INFO] Handling signal: term` and then `Error while closing socket [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` and then it won't start up again saying `Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)`. This has been driving me nuts because prod goes down. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

I running with with FastAPI and I'm on gunicorn 21.2.0.

And I checked memory, that's not it.

Comment: Not sure this is a good place for that question. Might want to try on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: systemd has a lot of option for controlling how a service works. One option tells it to kill the service if it has been running to long. Some other options control restarts including how many times to retry before giving up and how long to wait between tries.

Comment: Thanks @Ouroborus, I posted in superuser. And I tried mucking with the systemd service file to explicitly terminate the PID, but that didn't seem to help.